# PhoneGap building BlackBerry Sample Project stuck at Receiving Response

Tags: cordova, blackberry-webworks

I was trying to learn how to use PhoneGap to build BlackBerry apps. I followed [Guide from PhoneGap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_blackberry_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Blackberry) and sorted out the Webworks SDK as well as retrieved the signing keys.

Then I used `ant blackberry load-device` trying to deploy the sample apps onto the real device. But the signing process seemed freeze forever, some of the *.cod file got signed, but most of them just showing "Receiving Response":

[image: sign tool]

And the command line output:

```
Buildfile: /path-to-sample/sample/build.xml

blackberry:

load-device:

generate-cod-name:
     [echo] Generated name: cordovaExample.cod

clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory /path-to-sample/sample/build

package-app:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /path-to-sample/sample/build/widget
     [copy] Copying 22 files to /path-to-sample/sample/build/widget
      [zip] Building zip: /path-to-sample/sample/build/cordovaExample.zip

load-device:
     [exec] [INFO]              Parsing command line options
     [exec] [INFO]              Parsing bbwp.properties
     [exec] [INFO]              Validating application archive
     [exec] [INFO]              Parsing config.xml 
     [exec] [INFO]              Populating application source
     [exec] [INFO]              Compiling BlackBerry WebWorks application
     [exec] [INFO]              Starting signing tool
```

I've tried twice, no luck in either of them. The difference is which *.cod file got signed in Signature Tool.

So could you guys help me to figure out why it got stuck at there? Cheers.

**UPDATE**

If I force quit the Signature Tool, I'll got the output like:

```
     [exec] [ERROR]             Signing failed
     [exec] RIM Wireless Handheld Java Loader
     [exec] Copyright 2001-2010 Research In Motion Limited
     [exec] Connecting to device...
     [exec] 
     [exec] Connected                 Loading /path-to-sample/sample/build/StandardInstall/cordovaExampleError: unable to open file
     [exec] Disconnected

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 22 minutes 4 seconds
```

I'm sure I got my device connected and able to communicate with my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few hours continuously re-trying on this signing procedure, I finally successfully got the binary signed.

Looks like the successful rate is between 6/10 to 7/10. Meanwhile I am pretty sure about my internet connectivity was good.

It's a weird problem, probably due to RIM's signing server or the sign-tool's bug. Just keep trying may resolve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

The signature tool the packager uses requires JDK6, 32-bit even if you are on a 64-bit machine. You can confirm which you have installed in **C:\Program Files\Java** or **C:\Program Files (x86)\Java**.

Generally you should only have one JDK/JRE combination installed, having multiple may interfere and the signer may still hang if it is accessing JDK7 (or a 64-bit version) even if JDK6, 32-bit is installed.

Comment: thanks, but as u can see on the screenshot i posted, the Signature-Tool can sign some of them, and each time it can successfully signed different *.cods. Is it a network related issue?